# Connecting Azure Data Factory with InfluxDB

Tags: azure, time-series, influxdb, grafana, azure-data-factory

I'm working on some time series data that I want migrated to cloud. Working in Australia and PIE is stopping me from using Time Series Insights, so I've decided to use InfluxDb as my Time Series database.
I've set up a Grafana VM on Azure and installed InfluxDB in it.
The task where I'm stuck is.
1. Import a csv file (with time series data) to blob storage using Azure Data Factory (Have done this)
**2. Use ADF to transfer the files to InfluxDb. (Need help here)**
3. Do cool stuff on the data (have nice people in the team who're experts in this task)

Need help in point 2. Appreciate you putting your time to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ADF doesn't support influxdb as data source/sink.
Here is [the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) ADF supported.